# Why does nuxt still need to hydrate for ssr static generated sites?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using nuxt to create some static websites which use data taken from an API. The idea was that I could have nuxt process the data from my API and spit out a totally static site for quick load times and low server requirements. For the most part nuxt is doing exactly this, however it still loads payload.js and state.js alongside the pre-rendered content
which doesn't make sense to me, as surely there's no need for hydration if the markup is already there?

It's annoying because these .js files are full of the API data which bloats the size of the site overall. And I presume nuxt is processing this data somehow on the client side which would surely increase load time?